# In Ransack update ranackers dynamically when a model gets updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack, arel, hstore

I have Company Customer and CompanyCustomerField models. Customers store the hstore values in a column "properties" - the keys are from the CompanyCustomerField#name field. When a new CompanyCustomerField get created i need to add the #name to ransack to make them searchable.

When a new CompanyCustomerField gets added and I go to the search form I get

```
undefined method `*_cont' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007ff670100978>
```

because the new field is not available for searching. If i shutdown my fails server and reboot it works because it gets it into ransack.
I don't know how to dynamically add the functionality into ransack. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Customer.rb. this puts all the searchable fields into ransack but doesnt update it when new ones get added. because this only gets called once.

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  # ['favorite_color', 'receive_email_marketing' etc etc]
  CompanyCustomerField.pluck(:name).each do |name|
    ransacker name.to_sym do |parent|
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:properties], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(name))
    end
  end
end
```

here is the search form:

```
#customers/index.html
<%= search_form_for @search, remote: true do |f| %>
  <% current_company.customer_fields.each do |field| %>
    <%= render "customers/search_fields/#{field.field_type}", f: f, field: field %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

#customers/search_fields/text_field
<%= f.label (field.name + "_cont").to_sym, field.name.humanize %>
<%= f.text_field (field.name + "_cont").to_sym %>
```

....
Even if moving reloading to controller, still same result.

CustomersController.rb

```
def index
  Customer.reload_ransacker
  @search = current_company.customers.includes(:owner).ransack(params[:q])
  @customers = @search.result.page(params[:page])
end
```

Customer.rb

```
def self.reload_ransacker
  puts "==="
  puts "reload ransacker"
  puts "==="
  CompanyCustomerField.pluck(:name).each do |name|
    ransacker name.to_sym do |parent|
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:properties], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(name))
    end
  end
end
```

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `foo_cont' for #<Ransack::Search:0x00007fba3c05d5b8>):
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

needed to override:

```
module Ransack
  module Adapters
    module ActiveRecord
      module Base
        def ransacker(name, opts = {}, &block)
          @ransackable_attributes = nil
          self._ransackers = _ransackers.merge name.to_s => Ransacker
            .new(self, name, opts, &block)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`@ransackable_attributes` needs to be reset to nil so in `def ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)` the instance var is nil and can reload

should be considered a bug in ransack.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost a same trouble, so I'll write by your code what helped to me.
After adding ransacker dynamically, you should reset ransackable attributes for that model.
so by your code, change customer.rb like this.

#customer.rb

```
def self.reload_ransacker
  puts "==="
  puts "reload ransacker"
  puts "==="
  CompanyCustomerField.pluck(:name).each do |name|
    ransacker name.to_sym do |parent|
      Arel::Nodes::InfixOperation.new('->', parent.table[:properties], Arel::Nodes.build_quoted(name))
    end
  end
  ransackable_attributes(nil, true)
end

def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil, reload = nil)
    return nil if reload
    column_names + _ransackers.keys
end
```